# Identifying Page Load Request based on Constructor Call in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, constructor

I have the following scenario in my project based on JSF and RF3.3

1.Each of the operation in the application is traced. That is if user opens a certain page the information about the page is stored against the name of the user.

Now the pages can be createSomething or ModifySomething...
This both pages are linked to the same backing bean since they belong to same module.

So when I trace information of user based on constructor call I cannot store the information as to whether the bean was loaded for createSomething page or ModifySomething page.

I want to get the name of the page or something unique using which I can identify whether the bean is loaded for CreateSomething or ModifySomething.

I want to know how can I trace or log information for only a page visit.i.e. user clicked on the page but didn't performed any action.

For any action performed on the page I can easily keep a record of it..

I cannot use Javascript...

Kindly guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the JSF view ID by [`UIViewRoot#getViewId()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIViewRoot.html#getViewId%28%29) as follows:

```
String viewId = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewId();
// ...
```

It will return the view identifier which is the unique path of the view root, such as `/create.xhtml` or `/edit.xhtml`.

An alternative is to let the page invoke a page-specific `<f:event type="preRenderView">` listener method. For example, only in the create page:

```
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{bean.prepareCreate}" />
```

with

```
public void prepareCreate() {
    if (!FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isPostback()) {
        entity = new Entity();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks again for the reply.Actually I was using viewID previously but it gives the context path(i.e. if my jsf page is inside two folders.it will give the path of two folders and then the name of the jsf page...)..I am kind of satisfied with this for the time being...However I am not able to figure out the second option..Can you throw some light on it...I will be very interested in trying out an alternative to viewId function...

Comment: The view ID does not return the context path itself. The view ID returns the context-relative path of the view. It's namely valid to have a file with the same name in different folders, so this distinguishment is important. As to the second option, I'm not sure what part exactly you don't understand.